# loading config class in start.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In start.php file in laravel4 ... have this code

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
$environmentList = array(
    'staging'     => Config::get('program.staging'),
    'production'  => Config::get('program.production'),
    'development' => Config::get('program.development')
); 
});
```

Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in /var/www/vhosts/engine.domain.com/app/start.php on line 39

I was wondering how to load "Config" class before this ... in start file

Comment: what environment are you loading the config from? trick question.. Laravel probably doesn't know _what_ environment you're in when trying to detect the environment, so it doesn't make sense to be able to allow it to load configuration values.

Comment: what if you add this code just before `returning` $app

Comment: `Config::get()` depends on `detectEnvironment()` to know which environment you are in so it can get you the correct configurations. But your `detectEnvironment()` depends on `Config::get()`. Even though if you managed to get pass "class Config not found", I think you'll face with more problems. Do you really need to use `Config` at this point?

Comment: A bit off topic... you are also not returning anything from that anonymous function. It should return a simple string to `detectEnvironment()`. Can you tell us a bit more of what you are trying to achieve here by using `Config::get()`?

Answer (score -1):

What I was trying to do was loading different servers for staging and production for different partners based on url.

the way i was trying to do it created a paradox .. so I did this

```
$program = (object) include 'config/program.php';

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () use ($program){
$environmentList = array(
    'staging'     => array($program->staging),
    'production'  => array($program->production),
    'development' => array($program->development)
);
});
```

just don't use the Config:: here ... store the values in a variable instead.

Comment: -1 Edit your question, don't use the answer to extend your question